# Parameterization of closed spherical elastic curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, spherical-geometry

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.11597.pdf) provides an expression of the spherical $p$-elastic curves (bottom of page 9) and claims that this expression is obtained by adapting the results of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlid=10.4310%2Fjdg%2F1214438990) which treats the case $p=2$. However I didn't find the expression of the spherical elastic curve $\gamma$ in the second paper. There's the so-called *wavelength* studied in the appendix but I didn't see it in the paper, hence my misunderstanding.

Would you know the expression of $\gamma$ for $p=2$? (similar to the one given in the first paper).